# Is it necessary that every framework must have a binary file if it have header files?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5

I have one project.

In that project a Private Framework is Included.

Actually in XCode I can only see it's Header file.

I want to see its binary file.

I am using XCode 4.2 compatible with ios 5.0 simulator.

How can I find the path of its binary file.....

Any idea where the binary file is being stored?

Is it necessary that every framework must have a binary file if it has a header files??

Comment: i Think the priavate framework only come with the header file only if you check Erica sadun's Dump Framwork for ios then you will check by dumping private framework you only get header files in the app..

Answer (score 0):

Usually a linked framework :

1. is part of the project. In which case you can find it with the file explorer, among the rest of the project's files.
2. is linked from your project. In wich case you can:

   1. Click on the project within the project's file explorer
   2. click on the "build phases" tab
   3. click on the linked framework.
   4. right-click over it
   5. click "show in finder", and you will get to where the binary is located

Answer (score 0):

A part from disassembly, there is no special interest on binaries. 
In regard the relationship between *.h files and binaries, you should refer to the old-beloved    pass between C->obj's-> exe.

In traditional programming every *.C / * Cpp (and cocoa *m, too) generates a obj, a binary representation of istructions. So every *C has its own *.h file.

When You don't want to give sources to a customer, you give only .obj (a Library IS a variant of an obj...) and *.h so other programmers can call your functions.
Is needed a *h file for this purpose? strictly NO: a programmer can calla function whose proto is unknown: the linker will resolve it. but:
1) the compiler will warn You have no proto the function you are calling
2) the compiler cannot check syntax and type of parameters.